# D3 v4 ajust zoom to center

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

Is there an obvious d3 V4 equivalent to the V3 `d3.behavior.zoom()`

`.center([width / 2, height / 2])` syntax.

(I've searched around, and most working examples of manual zooming, etc run in V3... and the API docs don't mention it as best I can tell. )

I am trying to add manual zoom in/out buttons, using the example:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7ec977c95910dd026812 as a base, but with V4.

### Edit

[Harpal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/490332/harpal) show me an [example](https://embed.plnkr.co/kVw0rWMo728dmbm8EjuG/) working in d3 v4, but I don't know how to apply it to my project.

So there is my script:

```
//-----------------------------------Variables ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Alto y ancho
var w = 500;
var h = 500;
var padding = 0;
var coundata= 0;
var maxx = 0.30
var minx = -0.30
var maxy = 6
var miny = -6

//-----------------------------------CREAR GRAFICO SCATTER ----------------------------------------------------------------
//Funciones de escala
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([minx, maxx])
  .range([padding, h]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([miny, maxy])
  .range([h, padding]);

var rScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,5])
  .range([2, 6]);

//Eje x
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(xScale);;

//Eje y
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale);

//Crear el elemento svg
var svg = d3.select("#linegraph")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

//Colores
grupo = svg.append("svg:g");

var c2 = grupo.append("rect")
  .attr("width", (w/2) - padding)
  .attr("height", (h/2)- padding)
  .attr("transform", "translate("+w/2+","+padding+")")
  .attr("fill", "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)");

var c1 = grupo.append("rect")
  .attr("width", (w/2) - padding)
  .attr("height", (h/2)- padding)
  .attr("transform", "translate("+padding+","+padding+")")
  .attr("fill", "rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3)");


var c3 = grupo.append("rect")
  .attr("width", (w/2) - padding)
  .attr("height", (h/2)- padding)
  .attr("transform", "translate("+padding+","+h/2+")")
  .attr("fill", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)");

var c4 = grupo.append("rect")
  .attr("width", (w/2) - padding)
  .attr("height", (h/2)- padding)
  .attr("transform", "translate("+w/2+","+h/2+")")
  .attr("fill", "rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.3)");


var g =svg.append("g");

//Añadimos el eje x
var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h/2) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

//Añadimos el eje y
var gY = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2)  + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis);

nowData = []
var grupo2 = svg.append("svg:g");


//Creamos los puntos
var datos = grupo2.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nowData)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xScale(d[0]);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return 5;
  })
  .append("svg:title")
  .text(function(d) {return "Valor x: "+d[0] +"\n Valor y :"+d[1]; })

;
var grupoLineas = svg.append("svg:g");
//--------------------------------- ZOOM---------------------------------------------------------------------              
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  // Don’t allow the zoomed area to be bigger than the viewport.
  .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
  .translateExtent([[0, 0], [w, h]])
  .extent([[0, 0], [w, h]])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);


grupo.style("transform-origin","50% 50% 0");
grupo2.style("transform-origin","50% 50% 0");
grupoLineas.style("transform-origin","50% 50% 0");
svg.style("transform-origin","50% 50% 0");
gX.style("transform-origin","50% 50% 0");
gY.style("transform-origin","50% 50% 0");

svg.call(zoom);
function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  gX.call(xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale)));
  gY.call(yAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yScale)));
  grupo2.attr("transform",d3.event.transform);
  grupoLineas.attr("transform",d3.event.transform);
  grupo.attr("transform",d3.event.transform);
}
function resetted() {
  svg.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
}
d3.select("#zoom_in")
  .on("click",function(){
    zoom.scaleBy(svg, 2);
  })
d3.select("#zoom_out")
  .on("click",function(){
    zoom.scaleBy(svg, 0.5);
  })
//---------------------------------------Funcion mostrarDatos ----------------------------------------------------------            
function mostrarDatos(){
  nowData=[]
  grupo2.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nowData)
    .exit()
    .remove()
  if($("#eae").prop('checked') == true)
  {
    nowData.push(eaepunt1[coundata])
    grupo2.selectAll("circle")

  }

  if($("#arab").prop('checked') == true)
  {
    nowData.push(arabpunt1[coundata])

  }
  console.log(nowData)

  grupo2.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nowData)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xScale(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return yScale(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return 5;
    })
    .append("svg:title")
    .text(function(d) {return "Valor x: "+d[0] +"\n Valor y :"+d[1]; })
  ;
}
$("#eae").change(function()
{
  mostrarDatos();
});

$("#arab").change(function()
{
  mostrarDatos()
});
```

I apply the `("transform-origin","50% 50% 0");` but it not works correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it 2 things

- First, apply zoom directly to the center:

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  // Don’t allow the zoomed area to be bigger than the viewport.
  .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
  .translateExtent([[0, 0], [w, h]])
  .extent([[0, 0], [w, h]])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

grupopadre.style("transform-origin", "50% 50% 0");
svg.call(zoom);
function zoomed() {
  grupopadre
    .style('transform', 'scale(' + d3.event.transform.k + ')');
}
```

- Second, center the graphic when you zoom out:

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  // Don’t allow the zoomed area to be bigger than the viewport.
  .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
  .translateExtent([[0, 0], [w, h]])
  .extent([[0, 0], [w, h]])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

grupopadre.style("transform-origin", "50% 50% 0");

svg.call(zoom);
function zoomed() {
  grupopadre.attr("transform",d3.event.transform);
}
```

You need to create a group with all SVG content in this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that answers your question, but here you can see similar example in V4: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/db6b4335bf1662b413e7968910104f0f

You can find detailed documentation on the zoom behavior in D3 API Docs for version 4 and I don't think there exist a more "obvious" way that is not documented: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#zooming-d3-zoom

Comment: I see this example but the zoom is not aplied from center, is aplied from cursor position

Answer (score 0):

You could add `transform-origin` to a `style` attribute to the element on which you perform the zoom:

```
.style("transform-origin", "50% 50% 0")
```

**EDIT**

Working Plnkr [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/kVw0rWMo728dmbm8EjuG/)

Comment: Ok the example works, can you check the edit and say how i need apply in my script?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just d3.zoom() now

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
            // Don’t allow the zoomed area to be bigger than the viewport.
            .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
            .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
            .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
            .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

Comment: This works when you zoom out (the graphic is centered), but I need de zoom aplied to the center of graphic all time and not to the cursor position

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution I found:

```
function zoomed() {
    var scale = d3.event.transform.k; 
    grupopadre.attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
}
```