# d3.js v4 zoom to chart center (NOT MOUSE POSITION!!)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have one more problem with d3 zooming.

I try to zoom to the center of the graph (ignoring mouse position). But I don't find anything that works for me.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907047/d3-v4-ajust-zoom-to-center) but i don't get it work.

And didn't found anything in the docs.

Zoom behavior:

```
//zoom behavior
let zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([0.5, 5])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
  .. some behavior ..
  //center here?
  .. some behavior ..
}
```

I think this should be an easy thing to do and don't understand, why it's not documented clearly somewhere.

Please see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rzxa19kq/47/) for the whole thing.

Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rzxa19kq/50/) for the details.

Note, that this will disable the x-panning as well.

Here the relevant code:

```
function getBoundingBoxCenterX (selection) {
  let element = selection.node();
  let bbox = element.getBBox();
  return bbox.x + bbox.width/2;
} 

//zoom behavior
let zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 5])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
  let center = getBoundingBoxCenterX(rect); //rect is the charts parent which expands while zooming
  let chartsWidth = (2 * center) * d3.event.transform.k;
  d3.event.transform.x = center - chartsWidth / 2;

  rescaling operations with d3.event.transform....
}
```